# EF iQueryable Linq does not work for decimal value comparison

Tags: linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I am using EF 5 in vs2012. I am using DataContext and searching in a Iqueryable with some linq expression. I want to search a

```
var res= dbContext.Products.OrderBy(s => s.Id).AsQueryable();
if (startPrice > -1 && endPrice > -1 && (startPrice < endPrice))
{
     res = res.Where(s => (s.UnitPrice >= startPrice && s.UnitPrice <= endPrice));
}

var list= res.ToList();
```

Here startPrice, endPrice, UnitPrice all are in decimal type.
I have also added several conditions with this query. Everything works fine. But this comparison (for price) returns a blank json data. I have tried with decimal.Compare() method but no luck. Can you please help me in this regard. I am learning linq. But found no solution. If possible give some suggestion: what to search in google for this kind of solution?

Comment: Did you check the generated SQL?

Comment: yes. It added the comparison. But not working at run time. when i am calling ToList() Method

Comment: Can you check that startPrice and endPrice are correct? You can check with hardcoded values for testing. I have tired your example and it is working fine for me

Comment: yes i have checked them. It works in a different project But it does not works for EF web API project. in this example my variable "res" is "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery" type. Is this is a problem?

Comment: Sorry guyz, Problem solved. My database was huge and it was taking almost 10+ minitue for calling a toList() method. now bypassing this. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using Northwnd sample database

```
    decimal? startPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(400.5100);
     decimal? endPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(500.5100);

    var res = NDC.Orders.OrderBy(s => s.OrderID).AsQueryable();                        
                if (startPrice > -1 && endPrice > -1 && (startPrice < endPrice))
                {
                    res = res.Where(s => (s.Freight >= startPrice && s.Freight <= endPrice));
                }

                var l = res.ToList();

     foreach (Order dcl in l)
                {
                    Response.Write(dcl.Freight.ToString());
                    Response.Write("<br/>");
                }

and result is
458.7800
477.9000
487.3800
411.8800
424.3000
487.5700
400.8100
```